# Значение слова "победа"

Tags: этимология

В белорусском языке "победа"- это "перамога", в украинском - перемога.
Смысл которого  и составные части слова легко объяснимы, а  значение болгарского слова "победа", которое без изменений перешло в русский язык, непонятен. И почему в русском используется болгарское слово,а не белорусское?

Comment: "Беларуского" языка не существует. Пост отредактирован.

Comment: Как я уже отмечал, ваша неприязнь к словам Беларусь и беларуский, лежит скорее всего в области психологии, а не русского языка.

Comment: Это из области региональных различий в употреблении русского языка и связано с переносом самоназвания Беларусь из белорусского языка в региональную разновидность русского, практикуемую на территории Белоруссии. Никто против этого не возражает. В языке, на котором говорят в России, употребление названия (Республика) Беларусь вполне возможно при формальных ссылках на документы или в дипломатическом обращении, но даже в этом случае с нашей стороны невозможно употребить слово "беларуский" - просто его нет в языке, на котором говорим мы.

Comment: Alex_andr, Вы совершенно правильно говорите. Я просто устал уже это поторять. А о том, что наверняка найдется умная ьголова, которая потребует "беларуского" уродца я говорил еще в те времена, когда от самой "Беларуси" ещё только вздрагивали как от ночного кошмара. На грамоте можно найти.

Answer (score 0):

Победа

ПОБЕДА. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Производное от общеслав. poběditi "победить", преф. образования от běditi "убеждать" (от běda, см. беда). Победа буквально — "убеждение (силой)". В др.-рус. яз. имело кроме соврем. и противоположное значение "поражение".
(Шанский)

Comment: Слово "беларуский" в русском языке нет.